# How can I read and decrypt the file in iOS if it is an XML file and trying to store it in NSString to decrypt it?

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

```
NSString* pathss = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"documentary" ofType:@"xml"];    
NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathss encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];     
NSLog(@"content of file is: %@",contents);
```

It displays only the word **"U"**, at the place of contents.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/securing-and-encrypting-data-on-ios--mobile-21263

Comment: thanks for your help friend but i am not able to read the xml  file in nsstring form,, unless i don't store the the encrypted data in nsstring variable , i am not able to do anything. So can you help me reading the file in nsstring ??

Comment: @Rushabh Unless the file was encrypted with RNCryptor (or the RNCryptor protocol) it can not be decrypted with RNCryptor so the tut link will not help much.

Comment: you can try with NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathss encoding:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed error:NULL];

Comment: if not some where put you file and give link

Comment: @Jamil `NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed` is not an option for `NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`, it is an option for `NSData` so the code in the comment is incorrect. Also: when there is an error parameter, use it! If there is an error (nil return) the error parameter will contain a reason/description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a comment by the OP: "it is AES encrypted xml file"

If the XML file is AES encrypted it is comprised of data bytes, not characters and can not be represented as a UTF-8 string nor any string encoding in a useful way.

It is necessary to read the file into an `NSData`, not an `NSString`. AES decryption expects data, not a string as input and returns data as output. Since the  original input to AES was a valid XML string (as data) the resultant output data can then be decoded to the original XML string.

```
if (pathss == nil) {
    NSLog(@"pathss is nil");
    // Handle error
}

NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedXML = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathss options:0 error:&error];
if (encryptedXML == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Data read error: %@", error);
    // Handle error
}
else {
    // decrypt encryptedXML
}
```

Don't ignore the error handling and the `error` parameter, it will provide information about any error.

Decrypting the `encryptedXML` will require the encryption key, the encryption mode , padding option and possibly an iv (initialization vector).

Comment: thanks @zaph i read the file in nsdata form now i have the encrypted nsdata file and i am trying to decrypt it using RNCryptor library...  i used the code

Comment: NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedXML withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:pass error:Nil];
     NSString *encryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"encrypted data is :: %@",encryptedString);
i have 3 keys that were used at the time of encryption  and i.e -- HMACKey, password and salt how to decrypt the the encrypted xml file,, i have imported the RNCryptor library to decrypt that but i am not able to do that

Comment: RNCryptor uses a format that places all the parameters except the key at the front of the encrypted data, see the documentation on the site. If the XML was created with RNCryptor only the key needs to b supplied on decryption. If it was not the XML was not encrypted with RNCryptor it is unlikely that it can be decrypted with RNCryptor unless the methods was exactly the same and the additional information is prepended in the same format as RNCryptor. If you need more help create a new question with more information on the encryption along with sample hex-ascii data of all inputs/outputs.

Comment: or any one please answer and provide the solution if u can , the link is :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686645/how-can-i-decrypt-the-xml-file-in-ios-with-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-standard-in-andr ...  would be a great help.