# How can i decrypt the xml file in iOS with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding standard,in android the file has been decrypted ,all keys like salt, IV

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

```
      private static Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
      Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

      //a random Init. Vector. just for testing
      byte[] iv = "e675f725e675f725".getBytes("UTF-8");

      c.init(mode, generateKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
      return c;
  }


  private static String Decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {

      byte[] decodedValue = new Base64().decode(encrypted.getBytes("UTF-8")); // new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrypted);

      Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
      byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);

      return new String(decValue);
  }

  private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
      char[] password = "3x5FBNs!".toCharArray();
      byte[] salt = "S@1tS@1t".getBytes("UTF-8");

      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
      byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
      return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
  }
```

I tried to use RNCryptor but could not decrypt. Can anybody help me which library should i use because i have got the encrypted file and don't know how it has been encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use RNCryptor it is best to use it on both platforms.

From a previous question it seems that the encrypted data was bytes, not Base64 encoded.

The primitives supplied by Apple Common Crypto and are part of the Security.framework. The header to use is `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` and you will find the interfaces you need in `CommonCryptor.h` and `CommonKeyDerivation.h`.

Make an attempt for iOS and add the code along with hex dumps of all input and output parameters and data both for the Android and iOS code.

Comment: i found that the standard AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding does not support in iOS, will i have to update with AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding or it is ok to decrypt with the same standard??

Comment: PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding are different names for the same algorithm (well, almost the same algorithm, but I've never seen them implemented differently). It's one of many confusing names in crypto discussions.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, as i had read about padding in 5 and 7 are 8 and 256 bytes, so got confused.   I already have have an encrypted xml file and have to decrypt that , how can i do that  ... as i am a newbie...  and working for 1st time on encryption. Can you help me out out, i had sent the mail too for help.

Comment: Note that CBC mode is the default for Common Crypto AES. Common Crypto requires the key size to be explicitly stated, many other encryption libraries use the supplied key length as the key size.

Comment: I provide consulting services, and would be happy to discuss rates, but writing an iOS implementation of a custom encryption format is beyond what I can do on StackOverflow.

Comment: @dilshadhaidari If you provide all the necessary information and an iOS attempt I can help here. Otherwise I provide consulting services, and would be happy to discuss rates, but writing an iOS implementation of a custom encryption format is beyond what I can do on StackOverflow. Tip of the Hat to Rob for the comment text.